# Creating 2 beans of the same class with different constructor-args and using autowiring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

Hi I working on a project, in which I need to create 2 instances of bean of same class but different constructor-args. Right now have functionality only for "production environment", so I have xml file like:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.xxx.yyy" /> 
    <bean id="id1" class="someCompanySpecificURLForTheClass" scope="singleton"/>

  <bean name="name1" factory-bean="id1" factory-method="createFullClient">
    <constructor-arg index="0">
        <ref bean="someJSONBean"/>
    </constructor-arg>
    <constructor-arg value="productionEnv" index="1"/>
</bean>  

</beans>
```

Now I need to include functionality for testing environment also. So I changed the xml file to:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.xxx.yyy" />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.zzz.yyy" /> 

 <bean id="id1" class="someCompanySpecificURLForTheClass" scope="prototype"/>

  <bean name="name1" factory-bean="id1" factory-method="createFullClient">
    <constructor-arg index="0">
        <ref bean="someJSONBean"/>
    </constructor-arg>
    <constructor-arg value="${value.name}" index="1"/>
</bean>
```

In the 2 Java files, I use **@Autowired** annotations on the method of **setClients()** and on creating object of **someJSONBean**.

But I am receiving errors:

```
BeanCreationException: could not autowire method: public void com.zzz.yyy.sometthing.setClients(someCompanySpecificURLForTheClass) throws IllegalArgumentException and UnsupportedEncodingException.
nested exception is defined: NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: no unique bean of type(someCompanySpecificURLForTheClass) is defined: expected single matching bean, found 2(name1, name2).
```

I am new to spring framework. can anyone tell whats happening wrong, is the autowiring that i am doing wrong? how can i solve this?

Edit:
Here **someCompanySpecificURLForTheClass** is the same class and beans(name1 and name2) use this bean as a factory bean with different constructor-arguments.
I am using spring 3.1.
After searching a lot, I think I can use placeholder for the constructor-args value right? 
The above is the edited xml file being used.
Updated code in the Java classes:
1.

```
@ConfigAdapter
 class class1{

  @Autowired
  private someJSONBean obj;

  @Autowired
  @Value("${value.name:thisismyvalue}")
  public void setClients(){}
}

 @ConfigAdapter
 class class2{

  @Autowired
  private someJSONBean obj;

  @Autowired
  @Value("${value.name:thisismyvalue}")
  public void setClients(){}
}
```

But I get the following error:

```
ConversionNotSupportedException: failed to convert 'java.lang.string' to 'someCompanySpecificURLForTheClass'.
nested execption is IllegalStateException
Cannot convert 'java.lang.string' to 'someCompanySpecificURLForTheClass' of required type: no matching editors or conversion strategy found.
```

Am I specifying the annotation value wrongly?
Why is this happening?

Comment: What kind of the error do you receive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `@Qualifier` Annotation along withe `@Autowired`. Since your are creating two beans of the same class, spring does not know which one to `autowire`. You can give a hint using `@Qualifer("id/name")` annotation.

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("name1")
 //yourProperty
```

or

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("name2")
//yourProperty
```

Check out this [link](http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-autowiring-qualifier-example/) .

If you want to inject both the beans into your class, then your have two create two different properties, each pointing to a different instance.

```
@Autowired
@Qualifer("name1")
//property1

@Autowired
@Qualifer("name2")
//property2
```

Comment: Thank you that worked! Atleast didnt get any build errors. But when I execute the code through REST client and the server is started. I make request to suppose name1 bean first, I get the data. But when in that session only when I make request to name2 bean, i donot get any  data. It searches in the name1  constructor arg (productionEnv) only.?

Comment: But I am using scope prototype also(tried using the scope with name1 and name2 bean also) but still the same. And cannot use "request" scope, as its not a dynamic web project and gives error as this scope is not registered. What could be the problem?

Comment: By property what exactly do you mean? I did @Qualifier annotation on my setClients method, in both the java files.

Comment: Lets say in a controller class you need two different ids of the same class w, you can create two fileds/properties with getters and setters and annotate one of them with `@Autowired@Qualifer("name1")` and the other one with `@Autowired@Qualifier("name2")` , so that you can test both prod and test environments. However it would be helpful if you share the source code. Changing the scopes will not help in this case.

Comment: Its the same class, but with different constructor arguments and accordingly it should instantiate the bean with proper arguments. But now its its instantiating only one bean, and using that only when making request to another one also, when I have explicitly mentioned the qualifiers in the java classes.

Comment: The java classes are not controllers but @ConfigAdapter, if that makes a difference.

Comment: Sample code on how to create two instances of same class type can be created is in this link - http://pastebin.com/k47Y6tmQ  . CHheck if that is helpful. As mentioned earlier, it will be helpful if you share the source code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96419/discussion-between-user2696258-and-localhost999).

Comment: I have updated the question, please let me know if you have anything to say on it>